# How did Non-Federation powers view environmentalism?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-tos

Given that the Federation is generally described as a paradise, it's safe to say it's pollution free. We also got a general view of Ferengi views of environmentalism in the Deep Space Nine finale. How do the other powers of Star Trek universe view environmentalism?

**Please avoid any jokes about green women** ;-)

Comment: Once you’ve gone green, you never go back.

Comment: Ferengi don't care.

Comment: Since Gagh are part of the environment, Klingons clearly loved the envoronment.

Comment: Beyond what's already in my answer, are there any other races you'd like me to address before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 4):

This question could be pretty open-ended so I'll restrict it to a few of the main races depicted; Ferengi, Klingon, Cardassian

### Ferengi

Although Ferenginar is depicted as being somewhat unpleasant (at least to human eyes), it's evidently not polluted:

> a fetid dismal swamp, subject to a near-endless downpour. The capital city of the homeworld rises out of the swamp, a series of dome-like structures piled almost
>   haphazardly one atop another.

In [Little Green Men](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPBzj90Su8A) Quark makes it abundantly clear that **causing environmental damage to your own homeworld is anathema to the Ferengi**, despite their world-view that profit is king.

---

### Klingon

In the original continuity the Klingon homeworld is heavily polluted as a result of the destruction of Praxis. Their callous disregard for their planet's wellbeing probably extended to the home planet as well:

> The moon's decimation means an almost eighty percent loss of available
>   energy and a deadly pollution of their ozone...They do not have
>   sufficient resources to manufacture air shelters in large enough
>   quantities to sustain anything like their current population.

In the Abrams continuity things are far worse: According to [Scott Chamblis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Qo'noS);

> Ultimately, that took us to a place of trying all different kinds of
>   environmental pieces of **this overall picture of toxified Qo'noS**

and from Ben Grossman:

> “As we start to descend down through the atmosphere," stated Ben
>   Grossmann, "we had the idea to almost give it an underwater feel. We
>   figured that with that much humidity and moisture to create a toxic
>   cloud, you’d imagine there’s a lot of toxic sludge around.

---

### Cardassian

The Cardassians seem to have a "devil may care" attitude to pollution on their homeworld. Various companion books describe the [collapse of the farming industry](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Hevrit) due to industrial pollution, leading to famines which necessitated the need to invade their neighbours (setting the scene for DS9):

> **Weyoun:** *Did you know that when we arrived, children were starving on Cardassia Prime? It was heartbreaking.*